# Calling different extent of randomness of arc4random in Swift?

Tags: swift, arc4random

This might be rather stupid question. I would like to know if different nuances/extent of randomness would be possible using arc4random_uniform in Swift. Here's an example:

```
let number = arc4random_uniform(10) + 1
print(number)
```

In this case, a number will be printed randomly from 1 to 10. But is there a way that I can repeat the random result, 2 to 3 times? The result would be something like this:

```
1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9 ...

// 1) Randomly selected and 2) repeated 2 to 3 times randomly.
```

Perhaps I might use two arc4random_uniform functions together, but cannot express them properly. Would be much appreciated if you could give me some suggestions. <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, you will need to generate two values: your random `value` and a `repeatCount`.  Also, you'll need to remember both of those values so that you can repeat the `value`.  You can do this with a custom class:

```
class RandomWithRepeats {
    var range: ClosedRange<Int>
    var repeatRange: ClosedRange<Int>
    var repeatCount = 0
    var value = 0

    init(range: ClosedRange<Int>, repeatRange: ClosedRange<Int>) {
        self.range = range
        self.repeatRange = repeatRange
    }

    // generate a random number in a range
    // Just use Int.random(in:) with Swift 4.2 and later
    func random(in range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> Int {
        return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound + 1))) + range.lowerBound
    }

    func nextValue() -> Int {
        // if repeatCount is 0, its time to generate a new value and
        // a new repeatCount
        if repeatCount == 0 {
            // For Swift 4.2, just use Int.random(in:) instead
            value = self.random(in: range)
            repeatCount = self.random(in: repeatRange)
        }

        repeatCount -= 1
        return value
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
let rand = RandomWithRepeats(range: 1...10, repeatRange: 2...3)

// generate 20 random repeated numbers    
for _ in 1...20
{
    print(rand.nextValue(), terminator: " ")
}
```

> ```
> 6 6 6 8 8 8 10 10 10 2 2 9 9 5 5 8 8 8 5 5
> ```

Answer (score 2):

With regards to the nuances of random number generators: have a look at [GKRandomSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gameplaykit/gkrandomsource?language=objc).

What you're doing here is not really making something less random, or modifying the parameters in the random number generator. You're simply applying an operation (with one random parameter) to a collection of random integers.

```
extension Collection {

    func duplicateItemsRandomly(range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) -> [Element] {

        return self.reduce(into: [Element](), { (acc, element) in

            let distance = UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound + 1)
            let count = Int(arc4random_uniform(distance) + UInt32(range.lowerBound))
            let result = Array.init(repeating: element, count: count)
            acc.append(contentsOf: result)
        })
    }
}

let sequence = [1, 6, 3, 8, 9]
sequence.duplicateItemsRandomly(range: 2...3) 
// [1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]
```

P.S: If you're writing this code in Swift 4.2, please use [`Int.random(in:)`](https://learnappmaking.com/random-numbers-swift/).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a custom `Sequence`:

```
class RepeatingRandomSequence : Sequence {
    let rangeLow, rangeSpan : UInt32
    let repeatLow, repeatSpan : UInt32

    init(range:Range<UInt32>, count:Range<UInt32>) {
        rangeLow = range.lowerBound
        rangeSpan = range.upperBound - range.lowerBound + 1
        repeatLow = count.lowerBound
        repeatSpan = count.upperBound - count.lowerBound + 1
    }

    func makeIterator() -> AnyIterator<UInt32> {
        var count : UInt32 = 0
        var value : UInt32 = 0

        return AnyIterator {
            if(count <= 0) {
                count = arc4random_uniform(self.repeatSpan) + self.repeatLow
                value = arc4random_uniform(self.rangeSpan) + self.rangeLow
            }

            defer { count = count - 1 }

            return value
        }
    }
}

let sequence = RepeatingRandomSequence(range: 0..<10, count: 2..<3)
let randoms = sequence.makeIterator()
```

Note that the iterator, `randoms` now generates an endless sequence of random numbers using `randoms.next()`  Since the sequence is endless, many things aren't particularly useful, like `sort`, `map`, etc.  You could however use it like:

```
for value in random {
    print(value)
    if(value == 9) {  // or any other termination condition
        break
    }
}
```

Or more conventionally, as:

```
(0..<10).forEach { _ in
    print(String(describing: random.next()))
}
```